# How to make a jQuery event fire once

Tags: jquery

I have a basic image that lays over top the main container that fades in once a user visits the site.  I want this event to happen **only** on the initial load.  Can this be accomplished?

Here's the .js

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#landing').animate({opacity: 0.01}, 5000, function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $('#main').children().fadeIn(5000);
        });   
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's happening that makes the event fire again..? You could use [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/), but I'm not convinced it's necessary from the code you've posted.

Comment: Any time you visit that page again, the #landing fades in (which is just a full screen image).

Comment: @Ben: -1 for landing page images. ;-) (Not really, just theoretically.)

Comment: In which case cookies (as suggested by [Azriel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13893416/82548), below), or another form of local storage, is the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's subtle, I swear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set a cookie and then only run the animation if the cookie isn't set.

If you want to use jQuery then my recommendation would be to use this jQuery plugin:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

And the do something like:

```
if (!$.cookie('intro_animation')) {
    $.cookie('intro_animation', 'true');

    // Do your animation
    $('#landing').animate({opacity: 0.01}, 5000, function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#main').children().fadeIn(5000);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: how would I go about doing that in my current script? (I'm new to jQuery)

Comment: @Ben I updated the answer to provide specifics. Local storage is definitely also an option.

Comment: thanks for the help, going to look into this plugin for sure!

Comment: @Ben also you probably want to use `$(window).load` http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/